# Cordova android splash screen not cross fading with content

Tags: android, cordova, web-applications, splash-screen

I have a minor problem, i'm trying to make the splash screen cross fade with the content of my android app. The splash screen is fading to grey and than suddenly 'jumps' to my startpage. I would like the splash screen to gradually become more transparant, showing my startpage content.

I used the following settings in my config.xml

```
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />  
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />  
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give the Apache's splashscreen-Plugin a try.

Fortunately there are less preferences necessary in your config.xml:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="750"/>

<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>
```

But because of AutoHideSplashScreen set to false you have to remove the SplashScreen yourself:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){

  navigator.splashscreen.show();

  setTimeout(function(){
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
  },1000);

}, false);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm going to try this asap, let you know how it works

Comment: With Android phones it should fade out automatically, but this might depend on the android version. In one of my apps it does fade out automatically on an android phone (version 5.0.1). I'm not quite sure but this has not always been the case in former android-versions. Anyway Good luck :)